Why is the Qiskit Developer Exam given in v0.2x?
The most recent version of QisKit is 1.2.0.  I'm curious if there is a good reason that the developer exam is given in a deprecated version.
According to the website the exam is given in QisKit 0.2x.  This makes it particularly difficult to prepare for the exam, since I'm most accustomed to using the most recent qiskit version.  Is there an easy way to prepare for the exam using 1.2.0?  Or do I just need to downgrade and use 0.2x?

The Qiskit developer exam tests only the most basic concepts from Qiskit, which have not changed since v0.2X. However, the syntax has changed in a few places so it would be a good idea to use v0.2X (rather than v1.2.0) when working through the exam study guide.
That being said, I think they should (and probably will) update the exam with the new syntax.

I agree they should update the exam.  I'm hoping one of the qiskit developers will comment here and shed some light on why this hasn't been done yet.
